# Sugar ORM is slow

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sugarorm

I have got an activity within which there are five recyclerviews.
Each recyclerviews has got its data that is being loaded from web services.

Im using sugar orm to save and retrieve datas.

```
 JSONObject latestRingtoneTenJSONObject = dialogue.getJSONObject(i);
 String albumId = latestRingtoneTenJSONObject.getString("album_id");
 String title = latestRingtoneTenJSONObject.getString("album_name");
 String albumName = latestRingtoneTenJSONObject.getString("total_songs");
 String imgUrl = latestRingtoneTenJSONObject.getString("img_url");
 Log.d("Note", "saving");
 Dialog kbAlbums = new Dialog( albumId, title , albumName,imgUrl);
 SugarRecord.saveInTx(kbAlbums);
```

The problem is that Im getting the following warning,

> The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. It freezes my app

Imm using the ui thread to update the recycler view though

```
MainActivity.act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run(){
                                    loadRecyclerView();
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: Where and How are you loading your data from web services? are you doing it via in the main thread? Are you using retrofit or some kind of pattern? this kind of log happens when you are doing everything inside your activity/fragment, etc. Try to make your code decoupled meaning load the rest services via intent service, look into Model View Pattern design and try to incorporate that and see how that affects the speed of your application because it may not only be SugarORM causing this. This may also be a memory leak if the app freezes.

Comment: Im using volley to load datas

Answer (score 0):

The UI thread **is** the main thread.

It's far more likely that other parts of your code are causing the UI lockups, use the debugger to analyse which parts are taking longer. It's likely to be anything that relies on a network connection, in this case the `loadRecyclerView();`.

Consider doing the actual loading from a web service on a new thread, then only doing the actual view updating on the UI thread, for improved performance.